# UNIX- Using to 'find' to find duplicates of files

Tags: file, unix, search, find

Hi I have two directories a1dir1, and a1dir2. I want to find the files unique to each directories. This is a listing of both

```
$ ls -al ~david/a1dir1 --time-style=long-iso
total 56
drwxr-xr-x  4 david users  4096 2011-10-11 21:20 .
drwx--x--x 12 david users  4096 2011-10-03 16:42 ..
-rw-------  1 david users    60 2011-09-20 17:43 F3.DAT
-rw-------  1 david users    40 2011-09-20 17:43 f1
-rw-------  1 david users   270 2011-09-20 17:43 f2.c
-rwx------  1 david users  7539 2011-09-20 17:43 make.socket
-rw-------  1 david users   418 2011-09-20 17:43 make.socket.c
-rw-------  1 david users 11843 2011-09-20 17:43 prog1
-rw-------  1 david users   138 2011-09-20 17:43 prog1.c
lrwxrwxrwx  1 david users     4 2011-10-11 21:17 s.link -> f2.c
drwx------  2 david users  4096 2011-09-20 17:43 test1.dir
drwx------  2 david users  4096 2011-09-20 17:43 test3.dir
srwx------  1 david users     0 2011-10-11 21:18 unix.socket

$ ls -al ~david/a1dir2 --time-style=long-iso
total 192
drwxr-xr-x  5 david users   4096 2011-10-11 21:23 .
drwx--x--x 12 david users   4096 2011-10-03 16:42 ..
-rw-------  1 david users     39 2011-09-20 17:43 .hidden.file
-rw-------  1 david users     60 2011-09-20 17:43 F3.DAT
-rw-------  1 david users     40 2011-09-20 17:43 f1
-rw-------  1 david users     88 2011-09-20 17:43 file2
-rwx------  1 david users   7539 2011-09-20 17:43 make.socket
-r--------  1 david users 135838 2011-09-20 17:43 phones
-rw-------  1 david users    138 2011-09-20 17:43 prog1.c
-rw-------  1 david users    120 2011-09-20 17:43 prog2.c
lrwxrwxrwx  1 david users      4 2011-10-11 21:23 s.link -> f2.c
drwx------  2 david users   4096 2011-09-20 17:43 test1.dir
drwx------  2 david users   4096 2011-09-20 17:43 test2.dir
drwx------  2 david users   4096 2011-09-20 17:43 test3.dir
```

(I pass a1dir1 and a1dir2 as arguements) I tried:

```
for file in $(ls -al $1) 
do 
   find $2 -name "$file" 2> myerrors 
done
```

although this code just outputs every file in a1dir1? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Without find an example could be:

```
 diff -q trunk tmp/trunk | grep -v Common | grep -v differ
```

Comment: well the thing is, this is for an assignment so since my professor hasnt taught the Common and differ option I cant use them. And I have to format the output exactly as he shows. Ive tried for about three days but its hard to do it so simple since he hasnt taught much.

Comment: Sorry I didnt realize those were just parameters, Im used to seeing the parameters in quotes

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `diff` or `dircmp` depending on your OS/available software. Here's an example with GNU Diff:

```
diff --brief dir1 dir2
```

*Edit*:

From your comment, try this:

```
diff --brief dir1 dir2 | \
cut -c 9- | \
awk -F': ' '{print $1"/"$2}' | \
while read filename
do
  ls -ld $filename
done
```

Comment: I have to be able to format it exactly as my professor wants. I have tried listing both directories and piping them into files and using diff, but I have to display all information about each file

Comment: @user614573, please see the suggestion I made in the "Edit".

Comment: Well thank you that works better but the thing is I cant use "awk" which I why its so hard because I cant just compare file names with this or "sed" like I tried

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't handle filenames with spaces nor process subdirectories but anyway should run better than your code:

```
for file in $(ls -A $1) 
do 
   ls -l $2/$file 2>/dev/null
done
```

Comment: Well this still doesnt output the correct files, it produces F3.DAT, f1, make.socket, prog1.c, and s.link -> f2.c
Thats been my problem throughout each of my modifications I either get too many files or not enough shown. For example, the F3.DAT file I can never get right

Comment: Even if I list the contents of one directory to a file, I run through each file in the second directory and grep its name against the text file, it says ones that are inside there arent found

Comment: Sorry, I overlook your requirements and just tried to fix your script.